# Estimates for Bessel functions

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, bessel-functions

Are there known (above and/or below) estimates for the Bessel function $K_a(x)$? I am interested in the case where $x$ is positive real and $a$ is complex.

Answer (score 0):

For $x > 0$,
$$ K_a(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-x \cosh(t)) \cosh(a t)\; dt $$
If $a = b + i c$ where $b$ and $c$ are real,
$$ \cosh(a t) = \cosh(b t) \cos(c t) + i \sinh(b t) \sin(c t) $$
Estimate real or imaginary part, do the integration 
and you get a corresponding estimate for $K_a(x)$.
For example, since $-1 \le \cos(c t) \le 1$,
$$ |\text{Re}(K_a(x))| \le \int_0^\infty \exp(-x \cosh(t)) \cosh(b t)\; dt 
= K_b(x)$$
while since $-1 \le \sin(c t) \le 1$ and $|\sinh(b t)|\le \cosh(b t)$, you get the same estimate for $|\text{Im}(K_a(x))|$.

I'm sure there are better estimates.

Comment: Thanks. I do not accept because I want more subtle estimates. Namely, I am interested to catch an exponential decay along vertical lines, which appeared in my numerical experiments.

Comment: I'll try integration by parts in your approach.